# How I can get all themes and set specific theme of SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have tried to get all themes of SharePoint online using 
ClientObjectList themes = tenant.GetAllTenantThemes(); but failed.

I have tried this code but failed to get

```
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration;
using Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantManagement;

...

ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://mysite-admin.sharepoint.com/");
var pwd = "mypassword";
var passWord = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in pwd.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("admin@mydomain.com", passWord);
Tenant tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
ClientObjectList<ThemeProperties> themes = tenant.GetAllTenantThemes();
```

Error is:
The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Answer (score 2):

Use the code below to get all themes in tenant. Note: add ctx.load and ctx.ExecuteQuery methods.

```
string siteUrl = "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com";
string userName = "lz@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
string password = "xxx";
var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);               
    Tenant tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
    ClientObjectList<ThemeProperties> themes = tenant.GetAllTenantThemes();
    ctx.Load(themes);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach(ThemeProperties pres in themes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pres.Name);
    }
}
```

We can also use Pnp PowerShell to achieve it.

[**Get-PnPTenantTheme**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnptenanttheme?view=sharepoint-ps)

[**Add-PnPTenantTheme**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnptenanttheme?view=sharepoint-ps)

Set Theme for a site using this.

```
tenant.SetWebTheme("Custom Black", "http://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestModernTeamSite6");
ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
```

Comment: I am going to set the theme in a particular site but not working.  Code looks like:

var x= tenant.SetWebTheme("Custom Black", "https://mp.sharepoint.com/sites/TestModernTeamSite6");

There are anything wrong!